# error in obs studio

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, obs-studio

when i launch my obs then it shows
`OBS did not shut down properly during your last session. Would you like to start in Safe Mode (third-party plugins, scripting, and WebSockets disabled)?`
and then two buttons below it

```
1, run as normal 
2, run in safe mode
```

when i run it as normal then it shows obs interface for just 1sec and it turned off
if i run it in safe mode then it works normally

if i put my pc in sleep and come back then it isn't showing my screen in obs, instaed it just shows black screen
then i have to restart obs and then it automattically run in normal mode and whole over process.
i dont like that process repeting again and again